# How to set Default value in GridView Yii2

Tags: gridview, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I'm new in Yii2, and  i need a little bit help about GridView Yii2
[image: GridView Yii2]

I have tried to make a conditional like here :

```
   <?=
GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
         /*........Other attribute here..........*/
         [
            'attribute' => 'status_dosen',
            'value' => "status_dosen"==1 ? "Approved": "status_dosen"==NULL ? "Pending": "Rejected",
        ],
        [
            'attribute' => 'status_asrama',
            'value' => "status_dosen"==1 ? "Approved": "status_dosen"==NULL ? "Pending": "Rejected",
        ],

        ],
]);

?>
```

But i Got error then :

[image: Error]

> Unknown Property – yii\base\UnknownPropertyException
>   Getting unknown property: backend\modules\aitk\models\AitkRequest::Rejected

Anybody help me please..
How do we can set a default value with some conditional value?

For Attenttion and Help , I thank you.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use closure like that:

```
GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
             /*........Other attribute here..........*/
             [
                'attribute' => 'status_dosen',
                'value' => function ($data){
 return $data->status_dosen==1 ? "Approved": ($data->status_dosen==NULL ? "Pending": "Rejected");
}
            ],

    ]);
```

See [more](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-data-widgets.html#grid-columns)

EDIT:

Use css. Add in html or css file:

```
   .table-striped>tbody>tr:nth-child(odd)>td, .table-striped>tbody>tr:nth-child(odd)>th {
      background-color: red;
    }

.table-striped>tbody>tr:nth-child(even)>td, .table-striped>tbody>tr:nth-child(even)>th {
      background-color: green;
    }
```

Comment: It's work, but can you help me more??

i want, if it's Accepted, it colored with green, other red.. ??

how can i add some css ??

Comment: i want, if it's Accepted, it colored with green, other red.. ?? how can i add some css ??

Comment: I still  do not understand to use that CSS,  Where i should  put them ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to this code:

```
'value' => function ($model) {
    return getStatusHtml($model->status);
}
```

Some function:

```
function getStatusHtml($status)
    {
        $text = '';
        if ($status == 1) {
            return '<span class="label label-success>Success</span>';
        } elseif ($status == 2) {
            return '<span class="label label-default>Default</span>';
        } else {
            return '-';
        }
    }
```